# Bootstrap 3 data-toggle buttons-radio

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

It seems buttons-radio no longer works in Bootstrap 3

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button class="btn btn-default" value="1" type="button" >1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" "value="2" type="button" >2</button>
</div>
```

It has been replaced with radio button inputs.  Is there any way to bring back the only one button allowed to be checked in a group with buttons?  I need to be able to have the group be totally unpicked after one item has been selected so radio buttons won't do.

This ended up being the answer for me to keep using buttons in a radio type in BS3:

`$(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("active");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This ended up being the answer for me to keep using buttons in a radio type in BS3:

```
$(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("active");
```

Comment: I used this except `addClass("active")` instead of `addClass("current")`.

Comment: Yeah it seems like we have to use `$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");`

Comment: Using `addClass("current")` highlights the button as `active` until you click away and then neither are highlighted as `active`.  Using `addClass("active")` would be a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

Could you give all of the radio's the same `name=`? Then they'll toggle each other..

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radio1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radio2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="radio3" value="option3"> 3
</label>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/75922

Comment: Issue is that I need to be able to uncheck all of them.  I guess I could update everything to use radio buttons and use [http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/EtNXP/](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/EtNXP/) 

but I really was hoping there was some way to keep these as <buttons> and not use <input type="radio">

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
 data-toggle="button"
```

to each radio button

Source http://labs.thecssninja.com/bootleg/index.html#buttons

Answer (score 5):

Add input type="radio" inside tab:

```
<a href="#prices" class="btn btn-default active" data-toggle="tab">
    <input type="radio">Prices
</a>
```